# iOS : FCM Notification - Send push notification to multiple users at once?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

**The following function is used to send a notification to a user. How to send a notification to a multiple user at once?**

```
func sendPushNotification(to token: String, title: String, body: String) {
        let urlString = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!
        let paramString: [String : Any] = ["to" : token,
                                           "notification" : ["title" : title, "body" : body],
                                           "data" : ["user" : "test_id"]
        ]
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:paramString, options: [.prettyPrinted])
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("key=SERVER-KEY", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        let task =  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest)  { (data, response, error) in
            do {
                if let jsonData = data {
                    if let jsonDataDict  = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as? [String: AnyObject] {
                        NSLog("Received data:\n\(jsonDataDict))")
                    }
                }
            } catch let err as NSError {
                print(err.debugDescription)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send push notification to multiple users by adding multiple tokens.

Here receiverToken is multiple user's FCM tokens.

```
class func sendMultiple(title:String,message:String,receiverToken : [String]) -> ()
{
    var postParams : [String : Any] = [:]
    postParams = ["registration_ids":receiverToken,
                  "notification":[
                    "title":title,
                    "sound":"default",
                    "body":message],
                  "data":[
                    ],
                  "apns":[
                    "headers":[
                        "apns-priority":"10"],
                    "payload":[
                        "headers":[
                            "category":"NEW_MESSAGE_CATEGORY"]]]
    ]
    print(postParams)
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL.init(string: "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send")!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue(String(format:"key=%@", "YOUR_SERVER_KEY"), forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: postParams, options: [])

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler:
        { (responseData, response, responseError) -> Void in
            
    }).resume();
}
```

Please make sure to replace the "YOUR_SERVER_KEY" with your sever key